# CSS3 - transition-delay only on close?

Tags: css, css-transitions

```
a {
background: white;    
transition: background 1s ease;
transition-delay: 1s;
}

b {
background: black;
}
```

This makes the transition close after 1s, but also start.
Would it be possible to make it open immediately but close after 1s?

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3Yj79/embedded/result/ ?

Comment: Can't you do it without Javascript? I was looking for a CSS3 solution.

Comment: JavaScript is used to switch element class - how would you expect to make the transition happen without changing something?

Comment: Actually, I got it working on pure CSS. No need for buttons.

Comment: Post what you have right now to http://jsfiddle.net .

Comment: [No-js version, just use hover to toggle state](http://jsfiddle.net/3Yj79/1/embedded/result/), but that doesn't make any difference, unless I misunderstand your question (I'm assuming `a` and `b` are actually class names, not tag names).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G7zeK/ Oh right, just tags. Pardon me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code instead of yours. Let me know :

```
a {
  background: white;    
  transition: background 1s ease;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration:5s;
  }

b {
 background: black;
 }
```

Comment: No.. I need a transition-delay for close only. Your code has no delay at all.